# Point Feature is not shown in the map

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to create a QGIS Plugin in which the user is clicking on the map to get the coordinates which are used to create a point feature. However until now the point feature is not shown in the map. Here is the code I use:

```
le_koord = self.dlg.lineedit_Koordinate.text()
try:
    le_koord = [float(coord.strip()) for coord in le_koord.split(',')]
except:
    QMessageBox.critical(self.iface.mainWindow(),
    'Fehler bei der Eingabe!',
    "Es müssen durch Komma getrennte Koordinaten Lat Long eingegeben werden!..")
    return
            
x_koord = float(le_koord[0])
y_koord = float(le_koord[1])
            
layer_out = QgsVectorLayer("Point? 
crs="+str(project.crs())+"field=address:string&field=license:string",
                           "Lage",
                           "memory")
caps = layer_out.dataProvider().capabilities()
            
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    feature = QgsFeature(layer_out.fields())
    point_out = QgsPointXY(x_koord, y_koord)
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point_out))
    (res, outFeats) = layer_out.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
```

However, I only managed to make the point visible if I use `project.addMapLayer(layer_out)`, but as this creates always a new version of the selected layer, it is not usable. I found [this](https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-create-a-point-feature/) tutorial in which the same commands are used, but which is done directly in the Python console in QGIS.

I'm using QGIS 3.30 and Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: ~~Try using the `with edit(layer)` context instead of going low-level through the data provider. Or call `layer.triggerRepaint()` when you are done.~~ Actually, the code does not show the layer being part of the project at all.

Comment: PS you could use two QDoubleSpinBox widgets instead of a QLineEdit to get floating point numbers directly ;)

Comment: Last but not least, aren't you creating a new layer each time anyways? How do you add it to the project? If you don't add it (and it is not in the layer tree), it won't appear in your map.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Thanks a lot for your fast reply :) I just tried to use `layer_out.triggerRepaint()` but the feature is not appearing in the map. I want to create several points (later with distinct attributes) to the layer "Lage", as it is shown in the tutorial. Is this not possible, if I don't code directly in the Python Editor in QGIS? Thanks for the hint regarding QDoubleSpinBox, as soon I solved this problem, I will change it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates a new layer every time it runs.

The code you show is inside a function that is called after `self.dlg.lineedit_Koordinate` has changed, right?

What your code does is it creates a new memory layer every time your function is called.

You need to create the layer once (probably inside the class constructor) as something like

```
self.layer_out = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs="+str(project.crs())+"field=address:string&field=license:string",
"Lage",
"memory")
```

This layer needs to be added to the project.

Then inside the function that is triggered by user action just add to that layer (wrapped inside an edit context as mentioned in the comments):

```
feature = QgsFeature(self.layer_out.fields())
point_out = QgsPointXY(x_koord, y_koord)
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point_out))
(res, outFeats) = self.layer_out.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Yes that was my mistake, now I create `self.layer_out` at the beginning. But if I use this code for the project repeated times, I just realised I need to check if this layer is already created. If so, I need to use `layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByname('Lage')` to access this layer and asign it to the variable by `self.layer_out = layers[0]` . Is this the best way to code it?

Comment: Is your code the only place the layer can be created, or can a project exists where there is already a correct "Lage" layer that needs to be added to?

Comment: Yes, it is the code for a window to insert new data for the project. Hence it should be the only option to create a new layer, if it's necessary. The data is then stored in a PostgreSQL Database.

Comment: I would create the layer in the class constructor as `self.layer_out = QgsVectorLayer(...)`. In subsequent calls of your class methods you can then be sure the layer exists. As far as I understand it there is no reason to go via `QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName()`.

Comment: Maybe I have a wrong understanding in how it works. I followed your answer and it works fine, but if I only use `self.layer_out = QgsVectorLayer(...)`, I do not know at this point, if the Layer exsists already in the Map or not, I just would make sure it exists in the Code. Hence, what I think, is that I need to check with `layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByname('Lage')` if I need to add it with `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_out)` to the map or not.